# Issue with Worldpay on Store 2.4

Tags: expresso-store

I’ve just upgraded to Store 2.4 and now having an issue with the Worldpay payment gateway. I haven’t changed anything, yet I’m now getting the following error message on redirect to WorldPay:

> The transaction cannot be processed. Please send the following information to the merchant:
>   No cart ID supplied with the payment request.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: A temporary fix I came up with since the cartId isn't an essential item was to edit line 62 in store/vendor/omnipay/worldpay/src/Message/PurchaseRequest.php

`$data['cartId'] = "TemporaryID";`